# Jssor slider stays on the first image until I click it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

I've been modifying this javascript and trying to fix it but for some reason the slideshow stays in the first div/slide until i click or drag it, then it all works out.

My question is, how to get rid of this bug when it freezes at the page load?

The html document:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
                //Fade
                { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
            ];

            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                $AutoPlayInterval: 6000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 0,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                $SlideWidth: 795,                                //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                $SlideHeight: 600,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: false                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            };
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 795));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });
    </script>
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin-top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0; border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;">
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../../Downloads/slider-master/img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1920px; height: 600px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div id="slide-1">
                    TEST
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="slide-1">
                    <a id="slide-button" href="donera.html">Mer info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: blue;">
                <div>
                    <a id="slide-button" href="donera.html">Mer info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 05 css */
            /*
            .jssorb05 div           (normal)
            .jssorb05 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .av           (active)
            .jssorb05 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb05 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb05 div, .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av {
                background: url(img/b05.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .jssorb05 div {
                background-position: -7px -7px;
            }

            .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av:hover {
                background-position: -37px -7px;
            }

            .jssorb05 .av {
                background-position: -67px -7px;
            }

            .jssorb05 .dn, .jssorb05 .dn:hover {
                background-position: -97px -7px;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u="navigator" class="jssorb05" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; right: 6px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 16px; HEIGHT: 16px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 12 css */
            /*
            .jssora12l              (normal)
            .jssora12r              (normal)
            .jssora12l:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora12r:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora12ldn            (mousedown)
            .jssora12rdn            (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora12l, .jssora12r, .jssora12ldn, .jssora12rdn {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background: url(img/a12.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .jssora12l {
                background-position: -16px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12r {
                background-position: -75px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12l:hover {
                background-position: -136px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12r:hover {
                background-position: -195px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12ldn {
                background-position: -256px -37px;
            }

            .jssora12rdn {
                background-position: -315px -37px;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
```

Comment: Code looks clean at first sight... Any errors in the console?

Comment: (Clean except inline CSS and other minor things, I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

Open up your console, and you'll see that `#slider1_container` needs a width set in pixels.

Currently, it's `100%`. Changing it to something like `600px` worked for me.

This bug is caused by the `ScaleSlider()` function, which requires pixels to work.